# Azure WebJobs - multiple jobs different scheduling times in one deploy

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am trying to deploy WebJobs on Azure, where there will be only one WebJob continously running.

The want to achieve correct implementation for multiple jobs with different time schedules. So if one job is running once per hour and other ever 10 minutes, how can I achieve this without hard-coding values into the code or web.config?

If this is not they way, what would be the optimal way?

Comment: can you please give some more information like how your web job is being trigger ? is it queue trigger, blob trigger or anything else ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`TimerTriggerAttribute`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#timertrigger):

```
// Triggered every hours
public static void HourlyTimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:01:00")] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine("Scheduled job fired!");
}


// Triggered every 10 minutes
public static void MinutelyTimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:00:10")] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine("Scheduled job fired!");
}
```

Comment: In case anyone else wonders what version of the SDK defines the `TimerTriggerAttribute` class, it's in a separate Nuget package called **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions**.

Comment: On latest version you need to install the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` nuget package. let me know if it enough for u

Answer (score 0):

You could have one continuous WebJob running. The job would contain various functions, each listening for messages on a Queue, eg:

```
public static void ProcessHourlyTask([QueueTrigger("hourlytaskqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
{
     //do work
}

public static void ProcessDailyTask([QueueTrigger("daytaskqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
{
     //do work
}
```

You could use the Azure Scheduler to place messages on the appropriate Queue at the appropriate time. The WebJob method associated with that trigger is then activated.

Alternatively you could have one Queue where the queue message content determines which method to call.

I'm not sure what you mean by optimal, but in my experience using Queues is pretty easy and  works well, especially since messages that fail get retried (7 times I think) which is great as lots goes wrong in Azure (503's, dropped db connection etc)

Comment: is there possibility to use any annotations where you can set up scheduler inside of webjobs themselves? So basically you set up webjob as continous operation, and it runs internally depends on annotations

Comment: as @Thomas says you can install the extensions https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions